# Adding funcs, and triggers to test db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql

I have some custom functions and triggers, that were run as migrations and added into dev db. However when i run my tests - it seems like test db doesn't have these functions and triggers, and throws errors in specs, which using queries that requires these db-functions. I've tried to manually run
`rake db:test:clone` - but that copies only db structure, not its functions and triggers. How do i create full duplicate for db, keeping not only its structure, but also custom db functions, triggers and views?

PS: Db: postgres

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you use this setting:

```
config.active_record.schema_format = :sql
```

This would create a real sql file containing all details of your db.

And it would be loaded whenever you use `rake db:setup`

Before changing the setting, you could use `rake db:structure:dump` to create the sql file.

Comment: With that line, after running `rake test`, I still get triggers disabled in test database with Rails 5 and PostgreSQL :( I do have reasonable `structure.sql` and no `schema.rb`.